# Russian (or non-latin) filename load Qt Windows

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, utf-8

I'm trying to load files on a Qt/C++ software that include non-Latin characters.
The problem reported by a user with Russian filenames and I tried to quickly fix it with the code below.

Example filename was (I don't read or write russian!): Летний сад.dgr

```
bool QDepthmapView::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    m_open_file_name = fileName;
    m_redraw_all = 1;
    // this fixes the problem on a MacOSX but NOT on Windows!
    QByteArray ba = fileName.toUtf8(); 
    char *file = ba.data();
    // end of fix
    if(pDoc->OnOpenDocument(file)) // quick fix for weird chars (russian filename bug report)
    {
        // removed 
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above fix was a quick a dirty thing I found online, it works on my MacOSX10.8, but it seems that Windows handles non-ASCII chars a bit differently and I'm not familiar with it.

I'm looking for a multi-platform solution (the software runs on Win, Mac and Linux) for loading non-ASCII filenames.

EDIT regarding comments below:
`OnOpenDocument` goes to:

```
int QGraphDoc::OnOpenDocument(char* lpszPathName) 
{

   m_opened_name = QString(lpszPathName);

   int ok = m_meta_graph->read( lpszPathName );
// removed //

}

####
int read( const pstring& filename )
{
// cleared

#ifdef _WIN32
   ifstream stream( filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::in );
#else
   ifstream stream( filename.c_str(), ios::in );
#endif

//cleared

   stream.read( (char *) &version, sizeof( version ) );

// cleared
   }
####

template <class T>
istream& pmemvec<T>::read( istream& stream, streampos offset )
{
   if (offset != streampos(-1)) {
      stream.seekg( offset );
   }
   // READ / WRITE USES 32-bit LENGTHS (number of elements)
   // n.b., do not change this to size_t as it will cause 32-bit to 64-bit conversion problems
   unsigned int length;
   stream.read( (char *) &length, sizeof(unsigned int) );
   m_length = size_t(length);
   if (m_length >= storage_size()) {
      if (m_data) {
         delete [] m_data;
         m_data = NULL;
      }
      while (m_length >= storage_size())
         m_shift++;
      m_data = new T [storage_size()];
      if (!m_data)
         throw pexception( pexception::MEMORY_ALLOCATION, sizeof(T) * storage_size() );
   }
   if (m_length != 0) {
      stream.read( (char *) m_data, sizeof(T) * streamsize(m_length) );
   }
   return stream;
}
```

Comment: First things first - do you know the difference between Unicode and ASCII? Do you know that Windows, unlike Linux and OS X, does not use UTF-8 for filenames, so `char*` functions (like `fopen`) can't open non-ASCII filenames? And your question lacks sufficient information - what is this function `OnOpenDocument(file)`? Is it using an ASCII filename? Use `QFile` instead.

Comment: @RandomSeed No, Windows does not "encode file names in 'Windows-1252'". 1252 is an 8-bit encoding for the Latin alphabet (i.e. A-Z plus accents, no Cyrillic or any other non-Latin script). Internally, Windows stores file path/name characters using 16 bits.

Comment: OMG you're right. I've always assumed it was the case because `dir` (in console) displays file names correctly. Now I need to figure out what kind of dark magic this is...

Comment: @sashoalm I have added the OnOpenDocument function above.

Comment: @OHTO This doesn't make sense, the declaration of `pmemvec<T>::read()`  accepts 2 arguments - none of which is `char*`, but you pass it only a `char*`. This should result in a compile error. Are you sure you're posting the correct code?

Comment: @sashoalm corrected, I just one more step inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Windows local encodings.

Windows internally works in UTF-16 (as `QString` does), but its "legacy" narrow-char APIs work with the "local codepage", which normally is the same as the system codepage (although it can customized on a per-thread basis - <del>but no, it cannot be set to UTF-8</del> since Windows 10 1903 it's now possible!).

This means that most functions that work with `char`s passing them straight to Windows APIs (as normally happens with the C/C++ file facilities) expect strings encoded with the current codepage.

`QString` does support the `toLocal8Bit` method to provide a narrow-char representation of its content in the current system encoding, which should be the local CP on Windows and UTF-8 on any sanely configured UNIX.

Problem is, `QString` to UTF-8 is a lossless conversion, since they both can represent all the Unicode codepoints; `QString` to local codepage not so much - for example, Russian characters cannot be encoded in the usual Windows-1252 CP.

For this reason, using `toLocal8Bit` you can give the stream a file name in the encoding it expects, but you won't be able to open files that contain characters not included in the current codepage.

Long story short: the way that usually avoids any problem is to always keep paths as `QString` and open files with `QFile`. `QFile` deals internally with this insanity by calling the "widechar" versions of the Windows APIs with UTF-16 strings, and converting to UTF-8 as appropriate on UNIX systems.

If you really need to work with other file handling functions, you have two choices: either use `toLocal8Bit` and give up working on files with "non local" names on Windows, or provide a separated code path for Windows that works with `wchar_t`s (down to the wide-char version of C library and Windows API functions).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Qt version, if it Qt4.x.x, this code in main.cpp before QApplication should help:

```
#include <QTextCodec>
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me, I get the same error on Windows7-32bit.